# convert(_ rect: CGRect, to view: UIView?) does nothing when I pass nil to the view parameter

Tags: ios, swift, coordinate-systems

I am trying to get coordinates of the view in superview's coordinate local. So according to the docs if view is nil, this method will instead convert to window base coordinates. So In my case it did nothing, but if I pass view to it it works.

```
let zoomImageView = UIImageView()
let xoomImageView2 = UIImageView()
let xoomImageView3 = UIImageView()
let stratingFrame2 = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 150, height: 130)
let startingFrame1 = CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 200, height: 160)
let startingFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width:375, height: 200)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    xoomImageView3.frame = stratingFrame2
    xoomImageView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    xoomImageView2.frame = startingFrame1
    xoomImageView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    zoomImageView.frame = startingFrame
    zoomImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    zoomImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(animate)))
    zoomImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 //   zoomImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zuckdog")
    zoomImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    zoomImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(zoomImageView)
    zoomImageView.addSubview(xoomImageView2)
    xoomImageView2.addSubview(xoomImageView3)
    print(zoomImageView.frame)
    print(xoomImageView2.frame)
    print(xoomImageView3.frame)

    let newFrame = zoomImageView.convert(xoomImageView3.frame, to:  nil)
    print(newFrame)
```

Maybe someone can tell what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert in coordinates one major rule is

> View must be a subview to user coordinates conversion methods

Now look at your code

```
let newFrame = zoomImageView.convert(xoomImageView3.frame, to:  nil)
print(newFrame)
```

`zoomImageView`  is never been subview  `xoomImageView3` in your code and one more thing `xoomImageView3` has no DIRECT  relation with `zoomImageView` object

What you need to do is

First Convert  `xoomImageView3` Frame to  `zoomImageView`

```
 let xoomImageView3FrameAccordingTo_zoomImageView  = xoomImageView2.convert(xoomImageView3.frame, to:  zoomImageView)
```

now

```
let newFrame = zoomImageView.convert(xoomImageView3FrameAccordingTo_zoomImageView, to:  self.view)
```

Comment: please take another look to my code and take another look to docs, do not write a mess. Second i found out that it is only work in a strange manner when i use function in ViewDidLoad, if i use it in viewDidAppear it works ok. so maybe is there somehow hides real reason.

Comment: @N.Khasanov Really. Then pls try this MESS

Comment: @N.Khasanov Did you added that in you question. that it is working in ViewDidAppear ? Sorry to say you have very bad naming convention of your variables

Comment: you are in the wrong direction. thanks for your effort.

Comment: yes it works but thank you i dont need your help. i could not help me. thank you a lot. have a good day.

Comment: @N.Khasanov It is upto you Bro. Have a great day !!. Calling someone's effort to mess is very insulting before understand actual aim